# Google Search Console won't recognize 'brand' on WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo, google-search-console

Google Search Console is telling me that I'm missing 'brand' on my website while it's there.

Here is the error in Google Search Console

```
4 warnings
Missing field 'aggregateRating' (optional)
Missing field 'review' (optional)
Missing field 'brand' (optional)
No global identifier provided (e.g. gtin, mpn, isbn) (optional)
```

Here is the actual code on my website:

```
<div class="brand">
<a href="https://www.example.com/brands/alcon/">
<img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/alcon-min.png" alt="Alcon" data-lazy-src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/alcon-min.png" class="lazyloaded" data-was-processed="true"><noscript>
<img src="https://www.example.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/alcon-min.png" alt="Alcon" /></noscript></a>
</div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Hope is not to late for the answer.
Place this code in your theme functions (better made a functions in mu-plugins):

```
// Missing field brand and No global identifier provided
function adidoro_filter_woocommerce_structured_data_product( $markup, $product ) {
if (empty($markup['mpn']))
    $markup['mpn'] = $markup['sku'];
if (empty($markup['brand']))
    $markup['brand'] = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_brand' );   
if (empty($markup['brand']))
$markup['brand'] = array(
  '@type' => 'Brand',
  'name' => 'YOURBRANDNAME',
);
return $markup;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_structured_data_product', 'adidoro_filter_woocommerce_structured_data_product', 10, 2 );
```

Change YOURBRANDNAME, and be sure that is on your product page, not only in code. For ratings you need to have ratings on your products.